Quarto image missing with GitHub pages
I have been attempting to design my GitHub page for a data analysis portfolio.
I was doing well until I encountered a problem using the Quarto website codes. My headshot photo will not appear no matter what I do, am I making the reference to the image correctly?
In my index.qmd file:
title: "Dubem Okoye"
about:
    template: trestles
    id: ppc
    image: images/Headshot 2023.jpg
    image-shape: round
    image-width: 12em
    links:
      - icon: linkedin
        text: linkedin
        href: https://www.linkedin.com/in/dubem-okoye-83916a202/
      - icon: github
        text: github
        href: https://github.com/DubemOkoye

Here is the link to the full repository - https://github.com/DubemOkoye/data-portfolio
Please let me know if there are any additional information I can provide in this question or the rule of thumb for questions moving forward.
I tried removing images/headshot 2023.jpg, I tried changing the main branch from /root to /docs, and I tried making a separate folder in the repository with just the images/Headshot_2023.jpg, and changing the index.qmd to reference that instead of the images in the docs folder

I think it attempts to load the images from /images but the images are actually available under /data-portfolio/images.
